# How do I generate the slope of a regression function with a 90% confidence interval in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I'm working on a problem based on a data set that involves a copier business that provides service calls for their customers. The data set is a set of 45 instances that describes the number of minutes spent on a service call(v1), and the number of copiers the customer has(v2).

The problem is as stated:

Estimate the change in the mean service time when the number of copiers increases by 1. Use a 90 percent confidence interval.

I interpret this as creating a regression function to derive the slope, which is approximately the "change in mean service time when the number of copiers increases by 1". However, I don't know how to do this with a 90% confidence interval.

So far, the regression function is generated as like so:

```
data <-read.table("url")
lm(reformulate(names(d)[2], names(d)[1], data = d)
```

I got the following:

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)           V2  
-0.5802      15.0352
```

edit:

Running summary(), I get:

```
Call:
lm(formula = reformulate(names(d)[2], names(d)[1]), data = d)

Residuals:
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-22.7723  -3.7371   0.3334   6.3334  15.4039 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -0.5802     2.8039  -0.207    0.837    
V2           15.0352     0.4831  31.123   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 8.914 on 43 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9575,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9565 
F-statistic: 968.7 on 1 and 43 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The confidence interval for b1 (the slope) is:

b1 +/- t * (standard error)

So is this correct?:

15.0352 +/- (.4831 * 31.123)

Comment: The way you ask your questions, it's not really an R question, more of a conceptual one.

Comment: I'm not shutting anything down as I was also answering your question. Now that you have code in the question, it is actually R question.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that a "Wald Type" confidence interval would be calculated as b1 +/- t * (standard error).  However, the "t" in that equation is the critical t-value, and not the t-value reported in your model summary.

You can look up your critical t-value for a 90% CI with 43 degrees of freedom in R like this:

```
> # use 0.05 since it's a two-sided test
> qt(p = 0.05, df = 43, lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 1.681071
```

So then your CI would be b1 +/- 1.68 * (standard error).

You can double check this in R by using the `confint()` function.

For example:

```
mod1 = lm(reformulate(names(d)[2], names(d)[1], data = d)
confint(mod1, level = 0.90) # will give 5% and 95% values
```

Answer (score 1):

After you calculate the regression, you are going to have the coefficient estimate with statistics such as standard error. You can use those to calculate the confidence interval for the estimates.

**Update:**

Now that we have some code to look at, you can try this:

```
model = lm(reformulate(names(d)[2], names(d)[1], data = d)

summary(model) # gives you more information about the model
coef(model) #provides details about the resulting coefficients
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated my post with a result; can you take a quick look?